# Pass hash-sign-starting-string parameter to a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, parameters, scripting, ksh

I try to pass a string containted between two `#` sign to a ksh script :

```
Will #> ./a.ksh #This is a string#

Will #>
```

Nothing is prompted, the execpeted output would be :

```
Will #> ./a.ksh #This is a string#
#This is a string#
```

Below the `a.ksh` script.

**a.ksh**

```
echo $1
echo "$1"
echo ${1}
echo "${1}"
```

> I have tried to protect my `$1` variable by any means I knew but I
>   can't get anything starting with `#` to be displayed.

Those following don't work :

```
#> ./a.ksh #Hello
#> ./a.ksh #
```

But this do :

```
#> ./a.ksh Hello#
```

Any shell guru that could explain me why and how to get this to work as excpeted ?

I can escape those string using `\#This String#` or `"#This String#"` but I wonder why does `#` doesn't print by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is interpreted as the start of a comment. All comments are ignored by the interpreter.

You have two options:

1. Quote the string to make it a literal:

   `./a.ksh "#This is a string#"`
2. Have your script read input from the user instead of a parameter:

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Enter your text:"
read -r input
echo "You entered: $input"
```

then run the program first and enter your data after:

```
$ ./a.ksh
Enter your text:
#This is a string#
You entered: #This is a string#
```

Comment: On minor caveat.  `#` by itself does not start a comment.  Consider `echo foo#bar`.  A comment is started by a token that begins with #.

Comment: Such obvious that I missed it. Thank you!